# Toggling Flash on AVCaptureDevice requires Stopping and Starting AVCaptureSEssion

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In iOS 7 when changing the flash state for `AVCaptureDevice` using:

```
if ([self.avCaptureDevice isFlashModeSupported:self.avCaptureFlashMode])
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.avCaptureDevice lockForConfiguration:&error];
    if (!error) [self.avCaptureDevice setFlashMode:self.avCaptureFlashMode];
    [self.avCaptureDevice unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

The device won't use the flash unless the `AVCaptureSessions` is stopped and started with:

```
[self.avCaptureSession stopRunning];
[self.avCaptureSession startRunning];
```

This causes the camera to flash to black briefly. Is it possible to toggle the flash without stopping/starting the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar flash related problem in iOS7 where still capture would fail if the session had multiple outputs (still and videodata) and the flash was used. Found a workaround in https://devforums.apple.com/message/894764 (removing the second output before calling `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completion`). Obviously this will also pause the video, but it may be more suitable if you have a shutter animation anyway.