# AVCaptureSession freezes with flash on

Tags: ios, flash, camera, avfoundation

I'm not really sure what's going on here... The camera preview layer seems to freeze and the captureStill... block never gets executed. However, if I leave the flash off at the start of executing the app, it snaps the picture just fine. It should also be noted that I ran into this thread: [Toggling Flash on AVCaptureDevice requires Stopping and Starting AVCaptureSEssion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992029/toggling-flash-on-avcapturedevice-requires-stopping-and-starting-avcapturesessio) and decided to go ahead and try stopping the session and starting it again and it seemed to work. No more freezing, but the camera froze slightly when shutting off the session and turning it back on, which is not acceptable. Thoughts?

```
- (void)cameraButtonPressed{
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[device lockForConfiguration:nil];

if ([defaults objectForKey:@"Flash"])
{
    SPFlashButton option = [[defaults objectForKey:@"Flash"] intValue];

    if (option == SPFlashButtonTypeOff)
    {
        [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
    }
    else if (option == SPFlashButtonTypeOn)
    {
        [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
    }
    else if (option == SPFlashButtonTypeAuto)
    {
        [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeAuto];
    }
}
else
{
    [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeAuto];
}

[device unlockForConfiguration];


AVCaptureConnection *stillImageConnection = nil;
for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections) {
    for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ) {
            stillImageConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (stillImageConnection) { break; }
}

UIDeviceOrientation curDeviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
AVCaptureVideoOrientation avcaptureOrientation = [self avOrientationForDeviceOrientation:curDeviceOrientation];
[stillImageConnection setVideoOrientation:avcaptureOrientation];
[stillImageConnection setVideoScaleAndCropFactor:self.zoomScale];

[stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:AVVideoCodecJPEG
                                                                forKey:AVVideoCodecKey]];

[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:stillImageConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
    NSData *jpegData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:jpegData];

    //do stuff with the image
}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I didn't have photo set as the session preset. That's what was causing the freeze while trying to use the flash.

What I did:

```
 [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];
```

What I should have done:

```
 [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];
```